# Filling related entity when querying repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my repository, I get data from my TransportedMaterial table. I also 'include' TransportedMaterialPacking to retrieve all related data in this linked table. In this last table I also would like to retrieve the related MaterialPacking data. **I don't know how?**

[image]

On the picture above we see that the MaterialPacking is null (it has not been filled).

Here are the models:

```
public class TransportedMaterialPacking
{
    public int TransportedMaterialPackingID { get; set; }
    public MaterialPacking MaterialPacking { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public double? Width { get; set; }
    public double? Height { get; set; }
    public double? Length { get; set; }
}

public class MaterialPacking
{
    public int MaterialPackingID { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionFr { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionNl { get; set; }
}
```

The relations are like this:

TransportedMaterial >> TransportedMaterialPacking >> MaterialPacking

```
public static class ORMExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> MyInclude<T, C>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, C>> function)
        where C : class
        where T : class
    {
        return source.Include(function);
    }
```

I use Entity framework.

Thanks.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I updated my question to show MyInclude code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can 'cascade' include by doing something like `foo.Include("NavigationProperty.SubNavigationProperty")` in your query.

**Edit** Using property notation to include navigation subproperties is possible, see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx) for example.

Comment: frookypoon, DarinDimitrov: when I try to use .Include(...) in my query it get me errors on compile. I don't know why but Include is problematic but my custom function named MyInclude works (but not for multi cascade).

Comment: @Bronzato I updated my answer, see that link for examples. The key is basically to use `Select`.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do an .include("nav1.nav2") to load related entities

I don't know if  .include(x => x.nav1.nav2) will work